Tailwind breakpoints not triggering
I am trying to make a responsive header for my website. But tailwindcss breakpoints are not working!
This is my header.tsx:
export function TopHeader() {
  return (
      <div className="w-full">
        {/* Medium devices navbar */}
        <div className="hidden md:max-lg:block">
          <header className="bg-blue-500 text-white py-4 px-6">
            <div className="container mx-auto">
              <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">Medium Devices Navbar</h1>
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
        {/* Large devices navbar */}
        <div className="hidden lg:block">
          <header className="bg-green-500 text-white py-4 px-6">
            <div className="container mx-auto">
              <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">Large Devices Navbar</h1>
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

And this is my layout.tsx:
import Head from "next/head";

import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { lato, quicksand } from "@/lib/fonts";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/providers/theme-provider";
import { TopHeader } from "@/components/headers/top-header";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </Head>
      <body
        className={cn(
          lato.variable,
          quicksand.variable,
          "min-h-screen bg-background font-lato antialiased"
        )}
      >
        <ThemeProvider
          attribute="class"
          defaultTheme="system"
          enableSystem
          disableTransitionOnChange
        >
          <TopHeader />
          {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

None of the header is visible on my laptop screen. When I inspect using dev tools I see only hidden class and no rest of the class.

is this class correct? md:max-lg:block

yes it's correct

I think it should be md:block lg:hidden and if it is not, can you tell what you want to do with md:max-lg:block
